# Quick Sort (can't Passing the result)

Tags: sorting

I am absolutely HORRIBLE at passing functions, and even more so with passing arrays.I've problem with my code, I use Quick Sort for sorting my data from External File. The Function can't passing the sort result.

UPDATE : The Function can passing the sort but, sorting in small to big, I want sort big to small , how to do that ?

But if I use simple sorting Like

```
int temp_score;
    string temp_name;
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++)
        {
            if(score[j]>score[k])
            {
                temp_score=score[j];
                score[j]=score[k];
                score[k]=temp_score;
                temp_name=name[j];
                name[j]=name[k];
                name[k]=temp_name;
            }
        }
    }
```

No problem with simple sorting.

```
void quicksort(int score[],string name[],int kiri,int kanan){
int temp_score=0,i=kiri,j=kanan;
int pivot = score[(kiri+kanan)/2];
string temp_name;
//Pengurutan data berdasar Pivot
while (i <= j){
    while (score[i]<pivot){
        i++;
    }while (score[j]>pivot){
        j--;
    }if (i <= j){
                temp_score=score[i];
                score[i]=score[j];
                score[j]=temp_score;
                temp_name=name[i];
                name[i]=name[j];
                name[j]=temp_name;
                i++;
                j--;
    }
}
//Rekursif
if (kiri<j){
    quicksort(score,name,kiri,j);
}if (i<kanan){
    quicksort(score,name,i,kanan);
}
}

int main (){
string name[100];
int score[100];
int i=0;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        name[i]="";
        score[i]=0;
    }
    ifstream highscore;
    highscore.open("highscore.txt");
    while(!highscore.eof())
    {
        getline(highscore,name[i]);
        highscore >> score[i];
        highscore.ignore(100,'\n');
        i++;
    }

    quicksort(score,name,0,99);
    cout<<"\tNAMA\t\t|\t\tSCORE\t\t"<<endl;
    cout<<"========================================================"<<endl;
    for(int m=0;m<25;m++)
    {
        cout<<name[m]<<"\t\t\t\t"<<"Rp "<<score[m]<<endl;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort in descending order, you would generally replace '<' with '>', i-- with i++, limits are reversed - and I mean as a general guideline, not literally replace blindly everywhere. Ex:

```
int temp_score;
    string temp_name;
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++)
        {
            if(score[j]<score[k])
            {
                temp_score=score[j];
                score[j]=score[k];
                score[k]=temp_score;
                temp_name=name[j];
                name[j]=name[k];
                name[k]=temp_name;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can follow this guideline in your other code.

**EDIT:** Here is a snippet from your code the way you want. Note that I have inserted dummy data instead,

http://ideone.com/KAs1fG

Incorporate this in your code.

Comment: But, I confuse implemantation on quick sort funtion, To sort in descending order.

Comment: @MuhamadEnrinal See Edit.

Comment: I've already try your code, but there are problem, the data not sort.

Comment: @MuhamadEnrinal  : See my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

How To sort in descending order ?? I so confused

```
void quicksort(int score[],string name[],int kiri,int kanan){
int temp_score=0,i=kiri,j=kanan;
int pivot = score[(kiri+kanan)/2];
string temp_name;
//Pengurutan data berdasar Pivot
while (i <= j){
while (score[i]<pivot){
    i++;
}while (score[j]>pivot){
    j--;
}if (i <= j){
            temp_score=score[i];
            score[i]=score[j];
            score[j]=temp_score;
            temp_name=name[i];
            name[i]=name[j];
            name[j]=temp_name;
            i++;
            j--;
}
}
 //Rekursif
 if (kiri<j){
 quicksort(score,name,kiri,j);
 }if (i<kanan){
 quicksort(score,name,i,kanan);
}
}
```